# Css position fixed is misaligning span class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this little issue I haven't seemed to think deep enough to resolve.
I have got 3 divs with classes `.span3` `.span6` which is always the longest and `.span3` respectively. They are all within `.container .row` divs too. My issue now is that any time I try to make the position of any one of the divs fixed, they misalign and clash. 
For example, if I made the first div `.span3` fixed, div `.span6` would clash and take it's place.
Any contribution is duly appreciated.
Sorry for the brevity of my question, I was in a hurry.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="span3" style="position:fixed;">
        stuffs
       </div>
       <div class="span6">
        stuffs
       </div>
       <div class="span3">
       stuffs
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Those are the three divs(span3, span6, span3)]

[image]

Comment: I thought the question was clear enough, I've updated with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My quite easy fix was to apply `.offset3` class to the `div.span6` which shifted the overlapping div.

Thank you for your contributions @Attersson

Answer (score 0):

Please research

position: relative

position: absolute

position: static

Check this page for help:
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Apart from that I can't help unless you elaborate your question better. Also

> I have got 3 divs with classes `.span3` `.span6` which is always the
>   longest and `.span3` respectively

You repeated `.span3` twice. It makes your question more difficult to understand.

Edit:
A fixed position does not even take into account the parent anymore but the viewport (absolute coordinates of the document). It is then your job to align it. Perhaps you wanted to do something different. Check this page:

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Yes, I've got 3 those 3 different spans and they are responsive until I make any one of them fixed, then the fixed div becomes hidden below the next and the next div takes it place.

Comment: Please edit your question, provide your css and html, maybe screenshots of the problem... it is very hard to picture with too little detail.

Comment: I have added  one

Comment: But in your screenshot please mark what graphic element is what html element... even better if you can provide html and css

Comment: I've actually provided the html for it, the span class as you know is bootstraps.

Comment: I edited my answer. Well if you use a fixed position, the coordinates are no longer computed with trespect to the parent. So the position can mess up and you have to manually adjust it. I recommend not doing it. Please check the link I provided

Comment: I've been to the link and I really didn't find my solution.